# Which question about python-argparse is the duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

There are two questions that look to me like duplicates:

- [Parsing boolean values with argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008758/parsing-boolean-values-with-argparse)
- [Boolean argument for script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183936/boolean-argument-for-script)

**which one should be marked as the duplicate?**

The [Parsing boolean values with argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008758/parsing-boolean-values-with-argparse) has more answers, of the answers given there are more upvotes, the question is written more specific to `argparse`.

The [Boolean argument for script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183936/boolean-argument-for-script) was asked earlier.

Comment: i'm not exactly sure which one is better tho... the second/older one is more concise. but requires some rewriting before I could say it is better.

Comment: Drop by the [Python chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) if you want to discuss questions like this. Making decisions about duplicates is one of the things we're happy to help with.